# HidLibrary чтение нажатия кнопок с клавиатуры

Tags: c#

Консоль закрывается после нажатия любой клавиши, ни как не могу понять где ошибка, подскажите кто работал с этой библиотекой

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HidLibrary;

namespace MagtekCardReader
{
    class Program
   {
    private const int VendorId = 0x046D;
    private const int ProductId = 0xC52B;

    private static HidDevice _device;
    private static bool _attached;

    static void Main()
    {
        _device = HidDevices.Enumerate(VendorId, ProductId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (_device != null)
        {
            _device.OpenDevice();

            _device.MonitorDeviceEvents = true;

            _device.Inserted += DeviceAttachedHandler;
            _device.Removed += DeviceRemovedHandler;

            _device.ReadReport(OnReport);

            Console.ReadKey();

            _device.CloseDevice();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not find.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    private static void OnReport(HidReport report)
    {
        if (_attached == false) { return; }

        // process your data here
        var byteFromMyDevice = report.Data;
        Array.Reverse(byteFromMyDevice);
        //BitConverter.ToInt32(byteFromMyDevice, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToInt32(byteFromMyDevice, 0));

        //we need to start listening again for more data

       _device.ReadReport(OnReport);
    }

    private static void DeviceAttachedHandler()
    {
        _attached = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Device attached.");
        //_device.ReadReport(OnReport);
    }

    private static void DeviceRemovedHandler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Device removed.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: так вы по своей де логике ждете `Console.ReadKey();` и закрываете консоль

Comment: да, я проглядел что строка закомментирована `_device.ReadReport(OnReport);`, но в обработчике `DeviceAttachedHandler()` надо этуже строку удалить или закомментировать.